# Constraining generic parameters to be different types in Java

Tags: java, polymorphism, abstract-class, abstraction

I don't remember the correct name of this, that's why I can't Google it, so I'll ask this using an example, so it will inmediatly ring a bell.

This is for Java.

I'm using abstract classes and interfaces with bounded type parameters, just like this:

```
public interface DBInterface<T, E> {
    public int delete(T element);
}
```

My problem is that when I try to overload a function like this:

```
public interface DBInterface<T, E> {
    public int delete(T element);
    public int delete(E example);
}
```

The IDE complains about T may beign the same than E, so it thinks I'm declaring the exact same method twice (because, in fact, T could be the same than E in that declaration).

My questiosn are:

1. How is this called? I want to rewrite the question using proper terminology so it becomes more usefull for others in the future
2. How can I declase T and E in the interface to guarantee they will not be the same type?

Something like this:

```
public interface DBInterface<T, E != T> {
    public int delete(T element);
}
```

The way I'm doing it right now is by delimiting the legal types like this. Is it the correct way? Is there a way to allow ANY object EXCEPT the other one provided?:

```
public interface DBInterface<T extends DatabaseObject, E> {
}
```

Comment: I believe it gives that message because you could do this `DBInterface<Integer, Integer>` which will create two methods with the same signature. What can you tell us more about the limits of `T` and `E`?? I believe your last code sample is the only way to do it. You could have `T` and `E` be subtypes of a supertype `S` and only use `S` instead of `T` and `E`, no? Is there some "logic" connecting `T` and `E`?

Comment: Hi @ChristopherRucinski thanks for your reply. I know that is the reason, I've edited my question to show my current way of doing things. T is a type which allways implements another interface which is part of the package, so I can delimit it by using extend, however, normally E depends on another package implementation, and doesn't have a common interface or parent. It is allways passed down to functions that are never implemented in abstract classes (horrible design, but I've to stick to this, as I'm trying to adapt some old code changing as less as possible)

Comment: well, it seems like you need to create some layer between that `T` and `E` aspect of your code, and this interface. There isn't a way to do `<T, E != T>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a problem because the compiler has to use erasures of parameterized types for your methods. As `T` and `E` don't make it to the runtime, the compiler replaces your method parameter types in a systematic way.

As per the tutorial (check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html) and [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genMethods.html)), unbounded type parameters are replaced with `Object`, and bounds are enforced for bounded type parameters.
This is to say that your compiled interface method signatures are like this:

```
public interface DBInterface {
    public int delete(Object element);
    public int delete(Object example);
}
```

And your second version:

```
public interface DBInterface<T extends DatabaseObject, E> {
    public int delete(DatabaseObject element);
    public int delete(Object example);
}
```

I believe this makes the problem obvious for your first code snippet.

> How can I declare T and E in the interface to guarantee they will not be the same type?

This question can't accept an unqualified answer. The actual answer depends on the meaning of `T` and `E`. For example, it wouldn't make sense to suggest that these type parameters be bounded differently, because that may make no sense in some cases.

With that said, one thing that you should consider is renaming methods: I can't think of a `DBInterface` with two similarly typed parameters that don't play different roles. For example, the methods can be:

```
public int deleteById(T element);
public int deleteByKey(E key);
```

In other words, if we were to forget about single-letter generic type names convention, what would you name your type parameters?

```
public interface DBInterface<IdColumnType, PKColumnType> {}
```

I don't see why this shouldn't be applied to your method names, you have to acknowledge that you've allowed your users to pass the same class for both type arguments, after all... (that's to say that you'd technically still have a problem even if the compiler didn't do type erasure)

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer. Just for your curiosity, answering "I can't think of a DBInterface with two similarly typed parameters that don't play different roles." the reason is that there's an abstract method, genExampleFromElement(T element) which returns an element of type E. In most cases, delete(T element) invokes genExampleFromElement(element) and then calls delete(E example). I do this in this way because in most cases genExampleFromElement() is almost a ctrl+c / ctrl+v function which minor changes.

Comment: In some complex cases, the descendants can override the whole method if it doesn't respond to the more generic algorithm. Although, I would have called one "delete" and the other one "deleteByExample" or something, but I want to make it cleaner for future modifications and abstractions.

Comment: @DGoiko Thanks for shedding more light. My thinking is very abstract as you can tell. I'm just guessing that a meaningful difference must be applicable to the two parameters' methods at any concrete level/class. Thanks :-)